# Is there a good 3-way visual merge tool that integrates with Cornerstone or Versions

Tags: svn, merge, cornerstone

We're using svn and have relied on IntelliJ IDEA's built-in svn support. Cornerstone has some nice features which give you more power than IDEA in a lot of cases (timeline view for example) but their support for resolving complicated merge conflicts is basically non-existent.

Is there

a) some hidden r-click option I'm missing in Cornerstone to open some visual resolving window?
and/or
b) a good 3-way visual merge tool for OS X that Cornerstone can launch?

Answer (score 0):

[Araxis](http://www.araxis.com/) Merge can [directly access svn repositories](http://www.araxis.com/merge_mac/topic_plugin_subversion.html).